# merging lucene 6.2 indexing: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo

Tags: exception, merge, lucene

I wrote a code to merge lucene indexes. here is the code:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new ArabicTweetAnalyzer(true,true,true,true);
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        indexWriterConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        Directory fullIndexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(args[0]));        
        IndexWriter iWriter = new IndexWriter(fullIndexDirectory, indexWriterConfig);
        File indexesDir = new File(args[1]);
        File[] indexesFiles = indexesDir.listFiles();
        Directory[] indexes = new Directory[indexesFiles.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indexesFiles.length; i++) {
            indexes[i] = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexesFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        System.out.println("Merging...");
        iWriter.addIndexes(indexes);
```

I added the following jars to my class path:

- lucene-core-6.2.0.jar
- lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.0.jar
- lucene-backward-codecs-6.2.0.jar
- lucene-codecs-6.2.0

When I run the program I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.<init>(Lorg/apache/lucene/store/Directory;Lorg/apache/lucene/util/Version;Ljava/lang/String;IZLorg/apache/lucene/codecs/Codec;Ljava/util/Map;[BLjava/util/Map;Lorg/apache/lucene/search/Sort;)V
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat.java:198)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:362)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:493)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:490)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:731)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:683)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readLatestCommit(SegmentInfos.java:490)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addIndexes(IndexWriter.java:2487)
    at _general.LuceneIndexesMerger.main(LuceneIndexesMerger.java:36)
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum passed (4283f417). possibly transient resource issue, or a Lucene or JVM bug (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="D:\indexes\1\_0.si")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:379)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat.java:203)
        ... 8 more
```

I have no idea why I getting this exception and what are the missing jar files!
Any hints?

Comment: I'd check your classpath for old versions of lucene jars, particularly lucene-core.  Get rid of any references to lucene jars before 6.2.0.

Comment: Already checked the .classpath file, t only contain the new version of lucene jars. Any other hints?